# Associating localhost with multiple directories with LAMP on Ubuntu

Tags: localhost, lamp, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.10 and have just installed LAMP (with PHP 5) on my system.  I understand that the url

```
http://localhost/subdir/name.php
```

is associated, by default, with the file

```
/var/www/subdir/name.php
```

Is there a way to configure apache2 so that  localhost could be associated with more than one directory, rather like $PATH for executables?  IOW I am hoping to set things up so that

```
http://localhost/subdir/name.php
```

would not give a "404 Not Found" error if there was a file called

```
/var/www/subdir/name.php
```

or a file called

```
/home/peter/subdir/name.php
```

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Apache itself can only have one directory that is configured as the document root.  You could potentially do what you ask by configuring a `FallbackResource` using mod_dir, which would direct all requests that cannot be fulfilled to some script of your choosing and then use that script of you choosing to look in the alternative directory to serve up the resource.

So something like this:

```
FallbackResource /other_dir.php
```

Within `other_dir.php` you could then do something like

```
require('/home/peter' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This is super-hacky and not recommended.  I would be hard-pressed to think of a reason why you should do something like you are proposing to do.

Comment: I am developing php code using netbeans and wanted to test code that was developed in the ~/netbeansprojects directory.  I decided to use the procedure outlined in http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#specifyDocumentRoot.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour Oh, so you really don't want to serve up resources from two different web roots, you just wanted to create a virtual host?

Comment: That's probably the next best thing.  I could also configure netbeans to use /var/www, instead of ~/netbeansprojects, for the output but then I would have issues with ownership of /var/www.  Thanks, Peter.